# Are raw macadamia nuts better preserved with green soft skins on or off?

Tags: food-preservation, nuts

Are  raw macadamia nuts better preserved with green soft skins on or off?

When the soft skins go softer and softer and eventually bad, will that cause any damage to the hard-shelled nuts inside?